# Need advice using awk to create a single line from a file with multiple lines of info

Tags: awk

Using only awk, how would you convert the following text from this:

```
$ cat latest.csv
psga,alp1acscf0001vm001oam001p1n004v001,192.7.129.7,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm001oam001p1n004v002,192.7.129.8,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm002oam001p1n004v001,192.7.129.9,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm003oam001p1n004v001,192.7.129.10,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm004cif001p1n004v001,192.7.129.11,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm004cif001p1n004v002,192.7.129.12,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm005cif001p1n004v001,192.7.129.13,UVP
```

I managed to get the following output:

```
$ awk -F','  '{ print substr($2, 1, 14),  (substr($2, 1, 18)),$3 }' latest.csv
alp1acscf0001v alp1acscf0001vm001 192.7.129.7
alp1acscf0001v alp1acscf0001vm001 192.7.129.8
alp1acscf0001v alp1acscf0001vm002 192.7.129.9
alp1acscf0001v alp1acscf0001vm003 192.7.129.10
alp1acscf0001v alp1acscf0001vm004 192.7.129.11
alp1acscf0001v alp1acscf0001vm004 192.7.129.12
alp1acscf0001v alp1acscf0001vm005 192.7.129.13
```

However, I would like the first `substr($2, 1, 14)` **only once at the beginning of the line** and the remainder in a single line as below:

```
alp1acscf0001v alp1acscf0001vm001 192.7.129.7 alp1acscf0001vm001 192.7.129.8 alp1acscf0001vm002 192.7.129.9 alp1acscf0001vm003 192.7.129.10 alp1acscf0001vm004 192.7.129.11 alp1acscf0001vm004 192.7.129.12 alp1acscf0001vm005 192.7.129.13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, '
  { printf "%s %s %s", (NR==1 ? substr($2, 1, 14) : ""), substr($2, 1, 18), $3 }
  END{ print "" }
' latest.csv
```

This prints the first substring only for the first input record. The other substring plus `$3` is printed for all records.
In the `END` block, print a newline.

Comment: Thank you Freddy.
This method works perfectly!

Bjoern

Comment: Freddy, can you expand on your answer, what does 'printf "%s %s %s" 'do?

Comment: The "%s %s %s" is the format string to `printf`, it expects three arguments which are to be output as strings (`%s`).
I'm using it instead of `print` to omit newlines. Please read [Using printf Statements for Fancier Printing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html) in the gawk manual for usage and examples.

Comment: Ok, understood, thank you Freddy!

Answer (score -1):

command:

```
awk -F ","  'BEGIN{print "alp1acscf0001v"}ORS=" "{print substr($2,1,18),$3}' filename |perl -pne "s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
alp1acscf0001v alp1acscf0001vm001 192.7.129.7 alp1acscf0001vm001 192.7.129.8 alp1acscf0001vm002 192.7.129.9 alp1acscf0001vm003 192.7.129.10 alp1acscf0001vm004 192.7.129.11 alp1acscf0001vm004 192.7.129.12 alp1acscf0001vm005 192.7.129.13
```

Comment: Thank you Praveen.  

I should have mentioned that the $2 field varies all the time.